# Creating code to use either of two similar classes from external libraries

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I am working on a algorithm that is going to be used by two different teams who each have their own class type for the object the algorithm works on. I'd like to reduce duplication by having as much of my algorithm code as possible in common between the two classes.

To make things more concrete, let's suppose I am making an algorithm called Drive() that needs to work on both Cars and Trucks. Unfortunately there is no Vehicle class that both Truck and Car inherit from, but both Trucks and Cars provide access to all the methods and class members that the Drive algorithm needs. It seems unlikely that I'll be able to get these external teams to agree on a class to inherit from.

What is the best approach to a situation like this?

My current thought is to create a third class Vehicle, that can hold either a Car or a Truck, and then pass through calls to the class members/methods that I need for my algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of inheritance, this is a perfect use case for an interface.  You may be able to get both teams to agree to use an interface that defines the methods you need.  You have the IVehicle interface which defines the methods you need for your drive method. Then you setup your method to accept an IVehicle instead of a concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a perfect place to use the C# dynamic type.

Let Drive take an dynamic parameter and just pass your Cars and Trucks along

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 classes are in the same assembly, you can ask the 2 separate teams to agree on a common interface that both classes use which you can then make your code dependant on. If the classes are in different assemblies but both reference another common assembly, the interface could reside in that assembly instead.

The other alternative is to use the adapter pattern and this would be the better approach to using `dynamic` or if the teams won't agree on the interface themselves. To do this, *you* would create the common interface and also classes which implement it which can forward the calls on to the bespoke implementations.

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    void Turn(); // specify all the methods and properties you need here.
}

public class CarAdapter : IVehicle
{
    private Car car;

    public CarAdapter(Car car)
    {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public void Turn()
    {
        this.car.Turn();
    }
}

public class TruckAdapter : IVehicle
{
    private Truck truck;

    public TruckAdapter(Truck truck)
    {
        this.truck = truck;
    }

    public void Turn()
    {
        this.truck.Turn();
    }
}
```

Your code then just requires an `IVehicle`

```
public void Drive(IVehicle vehicle) { ... }
```

And could be called like this:

```
Drive(new CarAdapter(car));
//or
Drive(new TruckAdapter(truck));
```

An advantage tho this approach is that Car and Truck *could* have slightly different properties, method names or arguments etc but you encapsulate this in the adapter so your code just programs against `IVehicle`. This is also better than creating a single `Vehicle` which accepts a `Car` or `Truck` as in future if a 3rd class was required (say `Coach`) then you could create a `CoachAdapter` without having to change any of the existing `CarAdapter` or `TruckAdapter` code which allows you to follow OCP (Open Closed Principle - code should be Open for extension and Closed for modification), something you could not achieve with a `Vehicle` class as you would have to modify it to support coaches.